# JWT token is not working for AWS API gateway

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, jwt, aws-api-gateway, swaggerhub

We have around 10 .net microservices hosted on EC2,all the services are authorized using JWT token, each microservice is hosted on one port like 35.xx.xx.xx:8080 , 35.xx.xx.xx:8081 and so on. now I want to integrate these microservices to AWS API gateway , I have used swagger hub and integrated all the microservices to single end point in AWS API gateway(end point is **https://API ID.execute-api.region.amazonaws.com/stage**. After doing all this when I use authenticate I get JWT token generated, but I am unable to use the same token to get/post/put the data from other services. I get you are not authorized error. What configuration is missing here to send the JWT token to the endpoint.

Note : Same JWT token is working when I use individual endpoints

Answer (score 1):

Finally , I could solve myself , I just used Http proxy option and it got solved.